# Alternative means off authenticating GCP registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

So I am trying to get a list of images from GCP Container Registry. This HTTP API call works fine:

```
## generate token and save it
export TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) ## just to get a token
```

```
## make a call
curl -u "oauth2accesstoken:$TOKEN" https://gcr.io/v2/yourProject/yourImage/tags/list
```

However that workflow is problematic because `TOKEN` changes as `gcloud` generates it and for *reasons* I can't have `gcloud` as a dependency. Is there any way to authenticate a call like this above with a stable TOKEN/API KEY/ENV VAR? I like to be able to have a key that always works to deploy.

Comment: No. The tokens always need to be changed because those expire so there is nothing like a permanent token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See GCR [Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).

If you don't want to depend on `gcloud`, you have 2 options:

1. [Service Account key](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key).
2. [Standalone (no `gcloud`) Credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#standalone-helper).

In both cases you'll probably (!?) need to create a Service Account and keep the key accessible to the method you choose but be aware that using keys reduces security.

In some cases, you can use [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions) which federates e.g. GitHub credentials with a Google identity and avoids the need to generate a Service Account key.

Answer (score 0):

By default, access tokens are good for 1 hour (3,600 seconds). When the access token has expired, you must need to get a new token. The purpose of using short-lived tokens helps you implement the principle of least privilege across your identities and resources.

However you can use the 2 workaround:

1. Use a Service Account which will generate a [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key) does not expire. Service account keys can become a security risk if not managed carefully. You can check this documentation for [best practices for managing service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys).
2. You can also [extend the maximum lifetime to 12 hours](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#at-lifetime).

> Identify the service accounts that need an extended lifetime for access tokens, then add these service accounts to an organization policy that includes the constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension list constraint.